Do highly sensitive radio receivers experience less fading
I need to know whether radio receivers that are highly sensitive, like having sensitivity less than 0.0224 micro volts for AM reception, experience less fading than less sensitive radios.
Which specification of a radio receiver is responsible for mitigating fading?

Hi Prabhat, this uses the exact same wrong tags as this question about sensitivity that was deleted 13 minutes after you posted this here. You already have two accounts, both asking the same questions on different sites (1, 2). Don't you think a third account is a bit excessive?

Is this also the same person as user2166694 Atul Madan? @MarcusMüller

@RyujiAB1WX we can absolutely not say that for certain. But we see [tag:antenna] [tag:antenna-theory] [tag:antenna-construction] on this question, and we saw [tag:antenna] [tag:antenna-theory] [tag:antenna-construction] on the question of user216694's "Is it the AGC or the sensitivity of the radio receiver that mitigates fading?", both question that have nothing to do with antennas, so it's unlikely that two parties independently came to the conclusion that these would be the tags to use.

@RyujiAB1WX for reminder, you thankfully fixed the tags on that question.

Yeah those random variables are included in my joint distribution model and likelihood ratio test. @MarcusMüller

But at least his questions are somewhat improving in scope and clarity.

No. No one builds an AM radio with 0.0224uV sensitivity (about -149dBm on 50 ohm), but at that level of sensitivity, any extra gain is useless for any purpose (and practically speaking harmful because it reduces the dynamic range).
In short, if you can hear the atmospheric or environmental noise at an adequate level when cranking up the receiver gain (RF gain and audio volume), there is no use in having extra gain in the receiver, including mitigating fading.
Assuming adequate specifications, fading affects receivers equally, although a stronger AGC may equalize the audio output level more evenly. However, a stronger AGC does not mean superior performance or easier listening sound.
What helps mitigate fading in most reasonable receiving conditions is a sharply directional antenna, like Beverage antenna. If you have the land to have two or more Beverage antennas, you can do a diversity receiver.
